# How to stop at first occurence of match?

Tags: regex, match

I have here this sample:

```
received date
something
something
26/6/2013
.
.
due date
something
27/6/2013
```

I want to get just the first occurence of Received Date. I am trying to use this regular expression I have:

```
(?is)(?<=(invoice)?(?<!due.*?)date.*?)(\d{1,4}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4})
```

What I want to do is to get the date that either has a received preceding it or not, but to avoid getting if there is a prefix of due. I just want to get the 26/6/2013 .. also possibly, it would work the same with something like this:

```
date
something
something
26/6/2013
.
.
due date
something
27/6/2013
```

I am new to regex, and I spent a lot of time trying out different combinations but none seemed to work!

Please help thanks!

EDIT:

I am using Expresso..

Here is the output I am getting from the above:

```
26/6/2013
27/6/2013
```

Again, I only want to get the first one..

Comment: You should at least tell that you're using expresso :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
received date[\w\s]*(?!due date)[\w\s]*[^\d](\d{1,4}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4})
```

Group 1 captures date

OR

```
/received date.*?(?![\r\n]+due date).*?[^\d](\d{1,4}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4})/s
```

---

Comment: @user488792 try the second 1

Comment: Sorry, still no luck.. I don't receive any result and if I try to remove the "received" I still get both.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be simplified to: Get the first date.

```
(?s)(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}).*
```